# EditText cursor position on addTextChangedListener with currency format

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, textchanged

Is it possible to place cursor on selected position after changing the EditText content ?
I've made these codes :

```
binding.editText1.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {       }

override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
         val stringText = s.toString()

         if (stringText != current) {
              binding.editText1.removeTextChangedListener(this)

              val localeid = Locale("in", "ID")
              val format1 = NumberFormat.getInstance(localeid) as DecimalFormat
              format1.applyPattern("#,###.##")

              val doublecont : Double
              val cont = binding.editText1.text.toString().trim()
              doublecont = if (cont.isNotEmpty()) {
                        
            
           cont.replace("\\.","").replace(",","").replace(".","").toDouble()
                    } else {
                        0.0
                    }

              binding.editText1.setText(format1.format(doublecont))                 
             binding.editText1.setSelection(binding.editText1.text!!.length)
              binding.editText1.addTextChangedListener(this)
         } else {
              binding.editText1.setText("0")
         }
     }
})
```

I'm still confused with `setSelection()`, the result that I get from the codes above is the **cursor** will go to the end of EditText's character. What I want is when I move the **cursor** to position X, and type any number on it, the **cursor** will stay behind the newest number/character. Any idea for it ?

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly setting the cursor position to the end of the `EditText` with `setSelection(binding.editText1.text!!.length)`. Remember, this is happening in the *_after_TextChanged* callback, so the new text has already been added.

You need to handle this in [one of the other methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher#public-methods_1), which tell you the position where the change is happening (`start`), and how many characters are replacing how many existing ones (`count` means different things depending on which method it is). This way you can work out where the cursor needs to be.

I don't remember offhand if you can do `setSelection` in these methods or if it'll be overwritten later, but one thing you *can* do is set a temporary value inside the `TextWatcher` object:

```
object : TextWatcher {
    var selectionPosition: Int? = null
```

Then you can set that in the earlier callback, and use it in `afterTextChanged`. Basically working out where the cursor will need to go, and then later setting that position. And clear it when you're done - but if you always set it, it doesn't need to be nullable, since it'll always be set to the appropriate value before `afterTextChanged` fires.

Nice trick with temporarily removing the `TextWatcher` btw, I always add an *updating* flag to ignore changes. I'll have to use that next time!